# BizTalk WCF-BasicHttp Identity Editor field clarification

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl, biztalk, client-certificates

I'm trying to make it so my Send Port which is of type WCF-BasicHttp, will send a client certificate that will be accepted by the IIS server of the WCF service.

So far, as far as I can tell, the Client Cert is being attached (because when I put the wrong thumbprint value in there, I get a "Client Cert not found error"). However, now I'm getting an error as such

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
>   not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Which to me, sounds like something in processing the IIS SSL certificate is not working.

This service

- works fine when being called from another Winforms application, using
  the same Client Cert.
- is set to Require SSL
- is set to Require Client Certificates

Have a look at the image below...the only way I was able to the WCF to recognize a client cert was being attached was through configuring the send port as such:

[image: Identity Editor]

My question is, does this look correct? Notice the highlighted field, what is supposed to go in there? Is this the reason I'm getting the SSL/TLS error?

**EDIT** Or, do I have it all wrong, and the lower `Certificate Reference` area is not supposed to contain the Client Certficate?

Comment: Looking at the error it isn't the client certificate that is the problem, but it is the IIS server cert that isn't right.  If you launch IE as the BizTalk host and browse the the service URL, do you get any certificate warnings?

Comment: yes, I figured as much by the fact that I get an error when I remove the "Certificate Reference". I believe I have found my own answer and will post it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out, that in order to get it to work, I had to provide the **Service's** identity in the top portion. I noticed that putting anything in the Endpoint Identity dialog, after saving, a nice little bit of XML is written to the WCF-BasicHttp dialog after.

```
<identity>
  <dns value="myserver.mydomain.ca" />
  <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="[thumbprint]" isChainIncluded="False" />
</identity>
```

with only the lower portion filled out as in my question above, it provides the `<certificateReference>` portion, but the `<dns value="myserver.mydomain.ca" />` does not show up until you provide something in one of the textboxes in the "General" section. It worked when I provided either the DNS, or the Base64 of the server certificate.

So, I guess the answer is, once you fill out one of the sections, both are required, the send port is not going to automatically guess on the endpoint based on the address.